# Kotlin Unresolved reference: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, LOLLIPOP,Unresolved reference: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, android-gradle-plugin-3.3.0

I get an issue in my kotlin project with kotlin version 1.3.41 that
Unresolved reference:I'm not able to found out why that issue is coming?.
I also downgrade the kotlin version but no effect.

When I run it, I receive errors:

- Unresolved reference: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- Unresolved reference: LOLLIPOP
- Unresolved reference: statusBarColor
- Unresolved reference: PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION
- Unresolved reference: finishAffinity
- Unresolved reference: PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION
- Unresolved reference: finishAffinity
- Unresolved reference: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
- Unresolved reference: O
- Unresolved reference: IMPORTANCE_HIGH
- Unresolved reference: createNotificationChannel

Anyone can explain for me why this is so and fix it Thank you

```
    private fun requestReadWritePermissions() {
        TedPermission.with(this@ActivityChooseDocuments)
                .setPermissionListener(this)
                .setDeniedMessage(context!!.getString(R.string.permission_text))
                .setPermissions(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,CAMERA)
                .check()
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {}




# Project label gradle #
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.10"
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
    }
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

# App label gradle #
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rahman.kotlintaxi"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = false
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.1"

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: your receiving kotlin not configured ?

Comment: Can you please explain how can i ?

Comment: Same problem here. I updated kotlin version and it was working fine. I moved the project from some/path to /some/other/path and now it is not working. Deleted all idea files, no change.

Comment: for new project directory from android studio go to file and import project hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use just `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Use like this `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: I used Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but also not working

Comment: where i will share to screen shoot

Comment: Have you imported all classes for keywords that are in this error

Answer (score 0):

When I replaced `requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)` to  `requestPermissionLauncher.launch(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`, after this error was fixed